# Spring boot 2 tomcat ssl handshake caching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, nginx, tomcat

with nginx is possible to cache the ssl handshake like this (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-tcp/):

```
ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_session_timeout   4h;
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in SpringBoot 2 with Tomcat?

I'm asking because during our performance tests we see errors like the following (using Gatling):

```
 j.n.ConnectException: handshake timed out
```

If not is there any other options that can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Java's JSSE has already a default session cache of 20480 entries with an expiration of 24 hours.

If you want to change these values:

- on a the global level you can set the system property `javax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize` to the desired cache size (cf. [customizing JSSE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-A41282C3-19A3-400A-A40F-86F4DA22ABA9)),
- in an external Tomcat, you can use the properties `sessionCacheSize` and `sessionTimeout` of the [`<SSLHostConfig>`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig) element,
- when you use the embedded Tomcat server, you can define a [`TomcatConnectorCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatConnectorCustomizer.html), e.g.

```java
@Component
public class SSLSessionCustomizer implements TomcatConnectorCustomizer {

   @Override
   public void customize(Connector connector) {
      for (final SSLHostConfig hostConfig : connector.findSslHostConfigs()) {
         hostConfig.setSessionCacheSize(40960);
         hostConfig.setSessionTimeout(2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
      }
   }
}
```

**Remark**: You can use `openssl s_client -reconnect` to test the session resumption. However in recent versions of Java, JSSE aborts session resumption if the TLS extension `extended_master_secret` is missing (cf. [release notes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8192045)). Older clients, like those based on OpenSSL 1.0 do not support this extension. If compatibility is important for you, you can set the system property:

```
jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret=false
```